# Probability ploblem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A committee of 3 has to be formed randomly from a group of 6 people. Tom and Mary are in this group of 6. What is the probability that Tom will be selected into the committee but Mary will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\dbinom{6}{3}$ possible ways to form the committee in random. To count the favourable ways, force Tom into the committee, exclude Mary and choose randomly $2$ more out of the remaining $4$ persons, in $\dbinom{4}{2}$ ways. Thus, you conclude that the required probability is equal to $$\frac{\dbinom{4}{2}}{\dbinom{6}{3}}=\frac{4!3!3!}{6!2!2!}=\frac{3\cdot3}{5\cdot6}=\frac{3}{10}$$